# Не выпадает выпадающее меню

Tags: bootstrap

Вроде всё подключено, но выпадающие меню никак не хочет выпадать, на клик не реагирует, только при нажатии стрелки вниз выпадает, в чем ошибка?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <!-- зафиксировали сверху !-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu"> <span class="sr-only">Открыть навигацию</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Логотип</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Пункт 2 <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Выбор 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Выбор 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Выбор 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Выбор 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Название страницы</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <!-- в любом ряду 12 колонок !-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-md visible-lg"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet "/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js "></script>
```

Comment: Приложите в коде ваше выпадающее меню - сейчас его нет.

Comment: Обновил вам код в вашем вопросе. Одобрите правку. А комментарий с кодом меню удалите, чтобы не было лишнего мусора в вопросе и обсуждении. И посмотрите в правке, как оформлен код, с отступом - оформляйте так впредь.

Comment: Вроде одобрил правку, видно код ?

Comment: Теперь да, спасибо

Comment: Запустила Ваш пример, выпадающее меню открывается, на клик реагирует. о_О

Comment: Попробовал на 3 браузерах, везде одно и то же, если смотреть через консоль, то вот html код пункта 2(выпадающего меню):

    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Пункт 2 <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>

При нажатии загорается дропдаун который в <li> и false